# How to process an array and store it in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I want to basically assign classroom seats to students using an array. So I want to save that information along with the names of the students onto a different textfile, and I managed to do that with the names of the students but I am unable to assign seats, as I am not sure how to approach that using a single array. I basically want the program to assign seats using columns and rows like (1)(1), (1)(2)...etc. If its a 3x10 classroom then the row limit should be 3 obviously, and columns should be 10, but if the classroom size is 6x5, then there should be 6 rows and 5 columns. So depending on the classroom the user chooses, the array (assigning seats) should change.

Sample input:

```
Select Your Class Size!

A 6x5 Classroom or a 3X10 classroom?
 Enter '6x5' or '3x10' please!

6x5

Ok, so you have selected 6x5
Your classroom size looks like this:

XXXXXX
XXXXXX
XXXXXX
XXXXXX
XXXXXX

Now Enter The Number Of Students!
3

Enter the names of the 3 students!

George
Paul
Jacob

The Student Names And Seat Location Are As Follows:
George Seat Location:
Paul Seat Location:
Jacob Seat Location:
```

Sample Output:

Select Your Class Size!

```
A 6x5 Classroom or a 3X10 classroom?
 Enter '6x5' or '3x10' please!

6x5

Ok, so you have selected 6x5
Your classroom size looks like this:

XXXXXX
XXXXXX
XXXXXX
XXXXXX
XXXXXX

Now Enter The Number Of Students!
3

Enter the names of the 3 students!

George
Paul
Jacob

The Student Names And Seat Location Are As Follows:
George Seat Location: (1)(1)
Paul Seat Location: (1)(2)
Jacob Seat Location: (1)(3)
```

**NOTE:** If the user chose a 3x10 classroom, then the seat location would change accordingly, as there would be limitations on the number of rows and columns. if I chose 3x10 classroom, after (1)(3), the next persons seat location would be (2)(1), then (2)(2), (2)(3) then it would go onto next column ==> (3)(1)...etc until it reaches the max column. Can you help me in creating the array that does that? The names of the people and seat location should be saved in the textile called `StudentNames` **Note: The student names have already been saved, I am just struggling with seat location**

Code:

```
// Import scanner
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


// Create a class and method
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Clear the screen
    System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
    System.out.flush();

    // Create scanner object
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Create a print statement
    System.out.println("Select Your Class Size!\n");
    System.out.println("A 6x5 Classroom or a 3X10 classroom?\n Enter '6x5' or '3x10' please!\n");

    String Class1 = "6x5";
    String Class2 = "3x10";

    Double input[] = new Double[1];

    String selectClassSize = inp.next();

    int indexOfx = selectClassSize.indexOf('x');
    int xcount = 0;

    boolean containsx = indexOfx == 0 || indexOfx == (selectClassSize.length() - 2);

    if (containsx) {
      input[xcount] = Double.parseDouble(selectClassSize.replace("x", ""));
      
      System.out.println("\nOk, so you have selected " + Class1);
      System.out.println("Your classroom size looks like this:\n");

      int rows = 6;
      int columns = 5;
      int classSize[][] = new int [rows][columns];
      
      for(int i = 0; i < classSize[0].length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < classSize.length; j++){
            System.out.print("X");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }

      xcount++;

    } else {
      System.out.println("\nOk, so you have selected " + Class2);
      System.out.println("Your classroom size looks like this:\n");

      int rows2 = 3;
      int columns2 = 10;
      int classSize2[][] = new int [rows2][columns2];
        for(int x = 0; x < classSize2[0].length; x++){
          for(int y = 0; y < classSize2.length; y++){
              System.out.print("X");
      }
      System.out.println();
      }
    }

    // Create a scanner variable

    System.out.println("\nNow Enter The Number Of Students!");

    int numOfStudents = inp.nextInt();

    // Create a counter variable to count upto the numOfStudents and break the loop
    int counter = 0;

    System.out.println("\nEnter the names of the " + numOfStudents + " students!\n");


     try {

      // Initialize the new objects
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("StudentNames");
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

      String[] names = new String[numOfStudents];

      // Output the first names in the textfile
      for (int x = 0; x < numOfStudents; x++) {
        names[x] = inp.next();
        bw.write(names[x]+"Seat Location:");
        bw.newLine();
      }

      bw.close();
      fw.close();

      // Catch any errors
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("An Error Occured!");
    }
     try {

      // Initialize the new objects
      FileReader fr = new FileReader("StudentNames");
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

      String line = br.readLine();

      // Start a while loop to output the data from the file
      System.out.println("\nThe Student Names And Seat Location Are As Follows:");
      
      while (line != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        line = br.readLine();

      }

      br.close();
      fr.close();

      // Catch any errors
    } catch (Exception e1) {
      System.out.println("An Error Occured!");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi : D ermm i dun know mine version is correct for you or not but i hope it does....so my concept is i create a array for the seat then i just store all the seat matrix number to the array(since you does not mention about doess the seats number need to be random asign to each student) so i just according to the student and it will print out the seat number(column and row). let me know if i am wrong and have a nice day : D

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


// Create a class and method
public class grages {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Clear the screen
    System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
    System.out.flush();

    // Create scanner object
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Create a print statement
    System.out.println("Select Your Class Size!\n");
    System.out.println("A 6x5 Classroom or a 3X10 classroom?\n Enter '6x5' or '3x10' please!\n");

    String Class1 = "6x5";
    String Class2 = "3x10";

    Double input[] = new Double[1];

    String selectClassSize = inp.next();

    int indexOfx = selectClassSize.indexOf('x');
    int xcount = 0;

    boolean containsx = indexOfx == 0 || indexOfx == (selectClassSize.length() - 2);

    if (containsx) {
      input[xcount] = Double.parseDouble(selectClassSize.replace("x", ""));
      
      System.out.println("\nOk, so you have selected " + Class1);
      System.out.println("Your classroom size looks like this:\n");

      int rows = 6;
      int columns = 5;
      int classSize[][] = new int [rows][columns];
      
      for(int i = 0; i < classSize[0].length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < classSize.length; j++){
            System.out.print("X");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
      xcount++;

    } else {
      System.out.println("\nOk, so you have selected " + Class2);
      System.out.println("Your classroom size looks like this:\n");

      int rows2 = 3;
      int columns2 = 10;
      int classSize2[][] = new int [rows2][columns2];
        for(int x = 0; x < classSize2[0].length; x++){
          for(int y = 0; y < classSize2.length; y++){
              System.out.print("X");
      }
      System.out.println();
      }
    }

    // Create a scanner variable

    System.out.println("\nNow Enter The Number Of Students!");

    int numOfStudents = inp.nextInt();

    // Create a counter variable to count upto the numOfStudents and break the loop
    int counter = 0;

    System.out.println("\nEnter the names of the " + numOfStudents + " students!\n");
     try {

      // Initialize the new objects
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("StudentNames");
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

      String[] names = new String[numOfStudents];
      String[] seats = new String[numOfStudents];
      
      int row=1 , column = 0;
      
      // Output the first names in the 
      for (int x = 0; x < numOfStudents; x++) {
          names[x] = inp.next();
          if(containsx) {
              if(column>=6) {
                  ++row;
                  column = 0;
              }
          }
          else {
              if(column>=3) {
                  ++row;
                  column = 0;
              }
          }
          seats[x] = "("+Integer.toString(row)+")" + "("+Integer.toString(++column)+")";
          bw.write(names[x]+" Seat Location:"+seats[x]);
          bw.newLine();
      }

      bw.close();
      fw.close();

      // Catch any errors
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("An Error Occured!");
    }
     try {

      // Initialize the new objects
      FileReader fr = new FileReader("StudentNames");
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

      String line = br.readLine();

      // Start a while loop to output the data from the file
      System.out.println("\nThe Student Names And Seat Location Are As Follows:");
      
      while (line != null) {
          System.out.println(line);
          line = br.readLine();

        }

      br.close();
      fr.close();

      // Catch any errors
    } catch (Exception e1) {
      System.out.println("An Error Occured!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If i want to sort the names only and write it to the textile using Arrays.sort(), how would I do that?